# My Python code takes 10 minutes to run in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, performance, spacy, stop-words

I am attempting to remove stopwords from column 'reviews.text' in a .csv file. When I run the code, it takes 10 minutes for the output.

How do I speed up the run time?

```
import pandas as pd
from os import chdir, path
import spacy
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe('spacytextblob')

chdir(path.dirname(__file__))

file_path = 'amazon_product_reviews.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path, dtype={'id': str, 'name': str, 'asins': str, 'brand': str, 'categories': str, 'keys': str, 'manufacturer': str, 'reviews.date': str, 'reviews.dateAdded': str, 'reviews.dateSeen': str, 'reviews.didPurchase': str, 'reviews.doRecommend': str, 'reviews.id': str, 'reviews.numHelpful': str, 'reviews.rating': str, 'reviews.sourceURLs': str, 'reviews.text': str, 'reviews.title': str, 'reviews.userCity': str, 'reviews.userProvince': str, 'reviews.username': str, })

reviews_data = dataframe['reviews.text']

clean_data = dataframe.dropna(subset=['reviews.text'])

def preprocess_text(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    
    cleaned_tokens = [token.text.lower() for token in doc if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop]
    
    cleaned_text = ' '.join(cleaned_tokens)
    
    return cleaned_text

clean_data = clean_data.copy()
clean_data['processed_reviews'] = clean_data['reviews.text'].apply(preprocess_text)

print("Cleaned Data:")
print(clean_data[['reviews.text', 'processed_reviews']].head())
```

EDIT: I ran cProfile to see which areas of my code was taking the most time. See below my cProfile results:

```
  302681427 function calls (296741014 primitive calls) in 294.594 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     10/1    0.000    0.000  294.659  294.659 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.003    0.003  294.639  294.639 test3.py:10(main)
        1    0.000    0.000  293.915  293.915 series.py:4769(apply)
        1    0.000    0.000  293.915  293.915 apply.py:1409(apply)
        1    0.000    0.000  293.915  293.915 apply.py:1482(apply_standard)
        1    0.000    0.000  293.915  293.915 base.py:891(_map_values)
        1    0.121    0.121  293.915  293.915 algorithms.py:1667(map_array)
    34659    0.047    0.000  293.793    0.008 test3.py:29(preprocess_text)
    34659    0.465    0.000  293.253    0.008 language.py:1016(__call__)
   138636   32.197    0.000  242.236    0.002 trainable_pipe.pyx:40(__call__)
   138636    0.531    0.000  205.376    0.001 model.py:330(predict)
4678965/277272    1.998    0.000  203.319    0.001 model.py:307(__call__)
1628973/138636    2.245    0.000  187.239    0.001 chain.py:48(forward)
   242613    0.263    0.000  180.916    0.001 with_array.py:32(forward)
   519885  157.488    0.000  157.731    0.000 numpy_ops.pyx:91(gemm)
   346590    2.671    0.000  145.591    0.000 maxout.py:45(forward)
   103977    0.291    0.000  132.341    0.001 with_array.py:70(_list_forward)
   277272    0.548    0.000  127.896    0.000 residual.py:28(forward)
    69318    0.632    0.000  107.110    0.002 tb_framework.py:33(forward)
```

Comment: Have you profiled this code? Where does the code spend most of its time? Please provide a [mre]. We don't need the complete input data, but a sample of it will help.

Comment: That's a good question. Could you point me to a post that explains how to profile my code?

Comment: Not an answer... I'm not certain what is a "stop word", but honestly this is straight-forward enough... It looks like your reading in a complete buffer, running a list comprehension separating the buffer into many strings missing parts, then putting it back together.  Is there a reason you can't just take an in-pipe, send to the out-pipe unless the piece is alphanumeric and not a stop word (also have to mod the A or Z forget to convert to lowercase. That's what I'd do in C, it seems simpler than whatever this is but due to familiarity I could be just straight wrong.

Comment: Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646133/4583620) which shows how to run `cProfile` on the command line. Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60941705/4583620) which shows how to write `cProfile` into your script in order to profile a specific block of code. You can also check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).

Comment: Hard to say without the ability to run this, but you also could benefit from using iterators. Notice how preprocess_text and cleaned_tokens make their own complete copy of the full data set, rather than just doing some work on the small part they should be dealing with at one time?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @MichaelRuth . Please see the results of profiling.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that 10 minutes isn't normal, expected runtime for the size of your input? 0.008 seconds per item processed doesn't seem innately unreasonable on its face.

Comment: The profiled code spends the majority of its time (157s) in numpy_ops.pyx. Now, I'm pretty certain that the 32s spent in trainable_pipe.pyx is occurring within the numpy_ops.pyx along with some other stuff, but it's pretty clear that the greatest opportunity to reduce runtime is to look at what's happening during `Dataframe.apply()` and not `nlp()`. I think that @KennyOstrom's suggestion is the lowest hanging fruit here. You could use [mem-profile](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) to verify that memory may be causing performance degradation, but I'd just try converting to iterators.

Comment: Note that `str.join()` accepts iterables, which includes generator expressions. Worth a shot for how easy it is: `cleaned_text = ' '.join(token.text.lower() for token in doc if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to shave a lot off by only including processors from `nlp` that you really need!

I have a small test input set, so the results might not apply for a larger one as dramatically, but for me this gives a tremendous speedup:

```
def preprocess_text(text):        
    with nlp.select_pipes(enable="tagger"):
        return ' '.join(token.text.lower() for token in nlp(text) if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop)
```

A list of the pipeline processors, what they do and how to tweak them can be found from https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines.

Other than that, calling `apply` is always slow business in `pandas`, but I at least don't know how to solve this particular problem with vectorized operations.